# Multiple Forms that need to send their own email templates

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I've been searching around and cannot find a solution that works or fully explains how to set up multiple email templates each for its own form. All of my companies clients have multiple forms with different fields and need different information attached to this template. However all of our forms just use the template attached to the Contact Us form is using from the admin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using some extension to create multiple forms?

Comment: We are not using any extensions for our forms currently. We have just created multiple forms and call them on the page.  The issue is the email template that is being used when the forms are submitted. It is using the same email template for all of the forms. I need to assign a different email template being used by each form.

Comment: Did you create those new forms in Magento admin or manually (like in the code)? Sorry all the questions, just trying to understand your situation.

Comment: We created new files on the server for each form.

Comment: Yeah...I think that even have different files for each form, you are still using the the "master" form from Magento, and you can't assign different templates to them. You could try implement the solution bellow from Silver, or use an extension that allows you to create forms and assign templates.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar need and following is what I did.

1. Created a custom `.phtml` file under `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/custom/`. I created my html form here.
2. Created a CMS page in the backend and pulled it in a the CMS page `{{block type="core/template" template="custom/YOURPAGE.phtml"}}` you can use the CMS page directly if your form doesn't have php code.
3. Created a custom php file to send the email (your form in the custom phtml page should be pointing to this file). I couldn't paste my code here as I couldn't make this site to show it properly but you can easily find a php email code on w3 site or somewhere.